# Equalizing the summation of the amounts of two column which contains different set of amounts

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have two column (A,B), both contains 10 rows (A1-A10, B1-B10).

On A I have the amount 7000 and on A2 its 5000. On B1 I have 1500, on B2 I have 500, on A3 its 700, on A4 its 1100 and on A5 its 900.

On A10 I have the formula: =SUM(A1:A9)
On B10 I have the formula: =SUM(B1:B9)
Both the balance should be equal, to do that I want to put a formula on B9 which will be the amount that is needed to equal the balance.

What I have tried so far is: =A10-SUM(B1:B8)
That works fine. But I want to know that is there any other way to do it?

Comment: So this is an account. A is debit and B is credit. Last row in credit is balance. Why should there be any other way to do it?

Comment: Just want to learn all the possible way to do anything.

Comment: "learn all the possible way to do anything" :-) The answer is 42.

Comment: Didn't catch the meaning of 42!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is an account. A is debit and B is credit. Last row is balance.

You could have the balance variable on which side it occurs and so never lower than 0 according to historic accounting rules:

[image]

Formula in `A10`:

```
=IF(SUM(B2:B9)>SUM(A2:A9),SUM(B2:B9)-SUM(A2:A9),0)
```

and in `B10`:

```
=IF(SUM(A2:A9)>SUM(B2:B9),SUM(A2:A9)-SUM(B2:B9),0)
```

If sum debit is greater than sum credit, then balance is on credit side and vice versa.